# Access to props in data

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

can you tell me what I do wrong? I need access to props in my data object in component.

I have defined component like this:

```
  export default {
    components: {...},
    computed: {...},
    props: {
      userCode: {
        type: String,
        default: null
      }
    },
    data: () => ({
      options: {
        callback: function() {
          console.log(this.userCode) // prints undefined
          return ...;
        }
      }
    }),
    methods: {...},
    ...,
  }
```

prop value I define in router like this:

```
{
  path: '/user/bbb',
  name: 'users',
  component: userView,
  meta: {
    requiresLoggedIn: true,
  },
  props: {userCode: 'XXX'}
}
```

When I tried in same component render this prop in html like this `{{this.userCode}}` so it's worked and display my passed code. How to access to prop in options data object? Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a `computed` property instead of the `data` ?

Comment: @ThomasFerro I move options to computed by your advice, but now callback is not called
EDIT: now I also tried change this object to fucntion which return data, and it works as before .. instead property return  undefined

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what you're trying to do with the callback ? What's the purpose of the `options` data ?

Comment: @ThomasFerro it's object passed to third-party component (vuejs charts). When I tried to set static value of userCode which shouldn't be passed by props it works.

Comment: I think you should put the entire problem in your post, including the part with vuejs-chart and the entire `options` data. It will help us reproduce the issue and find a way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Vue.js best practices aside the reason `this.userCode` is undefined is because in that case the callback function defines its own `this` and the global `this` is not being used. To use the global this either use

`callback: () => {}`

or

```
callback: function() {
    console.log(this.userCode) // prints undefined
    return ...;
}.bind(this)
```

you can read more about the arrow function here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions